# Corona SDK: Image Format Optimization/info?

Tags: sprite, textures, coronasdk

we are used to develop for iOS platforms using Cocos2D, and there we have plenty of choice when it comes to image formats.

I cannot find any reference about how should we save our image assets for use within Corona, especially in relation to performance.

What I found out so far is only that PVR format is not supported (obviously because of the cross-platform support of the SDK). I seemed to find small hints that Corona uses 32bit pixel format for everything, so we cannot use different pixel formats as we do with Cocos2D.

Any CoronaSDK people out there that can answer me and/or redirect me to some documentation containing more details about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the confirmation in the Anscamobile forums - indeed, Corona SDK currently uses only 32bit pixel format for all textures, so there is no reason to save your images as 16-bit PNGs other than the size on disk of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Corona SDK now supports indexed pngs, 16-bit pngs, grayscale pngs... In fact any sort of png that you want to use.

But the only performance increase is the speed to load in memory (it GREATLY improves loading times) and space on storage.

I am using [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) and ImageAlpha to optmize my PNGs :)